# jQuery scrollTop() does not work in scrolling DIV on mobile browsers, alternatives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mobile-browser

I am trying to scroll to a specific location in a scrolling DIV.  Right now I am using a pixel offset with the jQuery scrollTop() function which works great on desktop browsers but it does not work on android mobiles browsers with the exception of Google's Chrome Android browser (do not have an iOS device to test if that works).  All the solutions I have found are for page (window) scrolling and not for scrolling in a DIV, anyone have any suggestions on what else I can use to accomplish the same task?

**Here is a example**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aQpPc/ 
http://jsfiddle.net/aQpPc/embedded/result/

**Other things I have tried that work in desktop browsers**:

```
document.getElementById('ID_of_element_in_a_DIV').scrollIntoView();
document.getElementById('ID_of_DIV').scrollTop = 200;
```

**EDIT 3/11/13:**

This is a know android browser issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

One user in the bug report suggested a workaround:

> because the issue only seems to appear when the overflow property is
>   set to scroll, you can first set it to 'hidden', set the scrollTop
>   property, then reset it back to 'scroll' (or auto).  The scrollTop
>   property seems to be honored when the element is re-rendered with
>   scrollbars.  It's not clear if this has any unexpected side-effects,
>   but "it works on my machine!"

Comment: it does work on IOS in both safari and chrome

Comment: For those in need to scroll for the whole document (like me), you could use $("body").scrollTop(0), trying it on html or div elements did not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aQpPc/embedded/result/ I tried this in the built in browser of my Samsung Galaxy S3 and it works just fine.

Comment: hey, fun to see my workaround quoted here. :)  That workaround still seems to be the only way I've found to get it to work in a reasonable way.  Doubt that this will be fixed any time soon...

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $(div).scrollTop(0)
}, 500 );
```

Answer (score 7):

A workaound that worked for me: first, temporarily set the overflow property to 'hidden', then set the scrollTop property, then set the overflow property back to 'scroll' (or auto).  The scrollTop value seems to be kept intact and honored when the overflow property is set back to 'scroll'.  This was a pretty trivial workaround that worked on all browsers I tested on (desktop and mobile).  I didn't test it exhaustively, and I didn't test with transitions in place, so there may be side-effects that I haven't encountered...  Your mileage may vary - but it's an easy thing to try.

Comment: does not work on Android 4.0.X browsers - when setting overflow back to 'scroll', whole div just goes to top ...

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer here http://blog.jonathanargentiero.com/jquery-scrolltop-not-working-on-mobile-devices-iphone-ipad-android-phones/

Mobile phones doesn't understand `$('html,body')` so u can do the following for mobile

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {           
    window.scrollTo(0)
} else {
    // default `$('html,body')` code for scrolling
}
```

**OR**

simply use `$('body')` instead of `$('html, body')`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window' after adding window.scrollTo(0);

Comment: @VivekVikranth what are you using can you share your snippet

Answer (score 4):

rather than using the scroll, scrollTo, or scrollTop methods (which give me problems in mobile), I recommend setting an ID on your top DOM element (like #top), and just using:

```
document.getElementById("top").scrollIntoView();
```

that works the best for me so far across all devices and browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple solutions for you to try. You will have to test them yourself, as I have not tried them in a mobile browser before, but here they are:

1. Use jQuery's `.css()` method (or `.animate()` depending on what your eventual goal us) to adjust the top margin (note: you would have to change the overflow to hidden and wrap the text in an inner div, which would be the element whose to margin you are adjusting)
2. Do the same thing as in the first solution, except set the embedded div's position to relative and adjust it's `top` attribute.

Let me know if you need help with any if this or have any more questions about this. Good luck! :)

Note that although I have not tested these in mobile before they are based on CSS standards, not jQuery functions, so they should work.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily setting the `overflow` property to 'hidden', as recommended in @Allan Nienhuis' answer, does not work on Android `4.0.3`, for instance (which is, e.g., what the Kindle Fire 2s are running) - when you set `overflow` back to `scroll`, the element scrolls back to the top.

Alternatives:

- Roll your own scrolling via a helper function, as demonstrated [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625#c24) - while this is simple to implement, it is bare-bones in that it doesn't give you inertial scrolling or overscrolling.
- Use a library such as [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5), which implements its own, sophisticated scrolling (inertial, overscrolling) based on CSS transformations.

Using iScroll requires a bit of setup, though: you need a *wrapper* `div` with fixed height and style `overflow: hidden` and the element to scroll should have *no* `overflow` style. [This jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mklement/gz4Sg/) shows how it's done.

Comment: iScroll works on 4.1 and it activates an anchor links! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way i could achieve scrolling to the top of the page on a Galaxy Tab was hiding the page `body` for 100ms while scrolling. Using jQuery:

```
$("body").hide();
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
setTimeout(function(){ $("body").show() }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's .animate method:

```
$('.div').animate({ scrollTo: x; });
```

Where x is equal to the position of the div you want to scroll to the top of.

Comment: Tried this also initially but this does not work.  I think jQuery (don't hold me to it) is using the underling javascript .scrollTop method but just stepping through positions to animate the scroll.

Comment: Actually, it's this: `$('.div').animate({ scrollTop: x });`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
$("html").scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Yup, that is the method used in the fiddle and discussed in the description of the first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1500);
});
});

<a href="#top" class="scroll"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$("body").animate( { scrollTop: 50,  },  800,  function(){
    $("body").clearQueue();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions did not work for me. I know someone mentioned mobile detection but their approach did not work for me. It finally dawned on me to use mobile detection to deliver two different CSS styles for each case. Maybe not ideal but it for sure works. Temporarily changing the styles with js also suggested above did not work for me.

I had a two column layout with independently scrolling divs, each set to overflow:scroll and the body had to be set to overflow:hidden. I need to use scrollTop on one of the columns and no solutions worked.

I used wp_is_mobile() (Wordpress function) and if mobile true, overflow: hidden is removed from *body* and the divs with overflow:scroll have that css removed. Finally, scrollTop worked on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } 
        else{
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
  
  $('.scrollup').click(function(){
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad|Android)/)) {           
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
    else{
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
        }, 500, function(){
        $('html,body').clearQueue();
      });
    }
  });              
});
```

```css
body{
  height: 1500px;
}

.scrollup {
    bottom: 135px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    display: none;
    background: #000;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    right: 12px;
    line-height: 36px;
    z-index: 25;
}

svg{
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollup">
    <svg height="35" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="30">
        <polygon points="396.6,352 416,331.3 256,160 96,331.3 115.3,352 256,201.5 "/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69271654/edit) your answer to add explanations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and solved it by using jquery `.offset()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
$('#yourFineElement').offset({ top: X, left Y)});
```

Comment: That would kill the entire layout as it positions the scrolling DIV itself across the screen (not affecting its scroll position).