# $(window).scrollTop() not working for mobile

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, mobile, scroll

`$(window).scrollTop()` is coming 0 for every scroll position in mobile.
Tried using $("body"), $(document). I need to find pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area in mobile. This piece of code works perfectly fine for Desktop.

Edit: Issue Resolved. 
Css issue. After I removed overflow-x: hidden from Body, its working fine now.

Comment: Have you tried `$("html").scrollTop()` ? Also your question implies that you haven't quoted body in $(body) (it should be `$("body")` ) is that a typo?

Comment: Yes i tried $("html").scrollTop() and $("body").

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260279/scrolltop-not-working-in-android-mobiles Sounds similar to this.

Comment: Have you seen the ScrollTo plugin? It's the only ScrollTo plugin I've found that seems to be fully mobile friendly. http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/