# How can I workaround window.scroll not working in iFrame on Android

Tags: javascript, iframe, android-internet

[`window.scroll` and `window.scrollTo` (its alias) don't seem to work on an `<iframe>` embedded in the Android 4.0.4 internet browser](http://jsfiddle.net/5H4Tg/2/). Nor do any of the other functions (it seems) like `window.scrollBy`, etc. How can I work around this limitation and force the `<iframe>` to scroll to a specific position on the page?

Some extra information:

- Solution doesn't need to be elegant, it can be a hacky work around. This is test code anyway.
- While the code doesn't need to be clean, it should be at least possible to make it cross-browser friendly
- Device is a Samsung Galaxy Note running Android 4.0.4 native browser
- Frame is in the same domain, so code can be run on it
- Other than the scrolling, I want to leave the page as untouched as possible
- The `<iframe>` has finished loading by the time my code runs

Comment: element.scrollIntoView() should still work. oh, and it's document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop, not window.scroll

Comment: Are you running the code from inside the iframe or from the parent page?

Comment: @dandavis `.scrollIntoView()` doesn't seem to work either. Also, `window.scroll` is a different function than setting `scrollTop` (which varies a bit between browsers)

Comment: @AndrewK Neither seems to work, but I will be running it from the parent page.

Comment: What element are you trying to scroll? The WebKit core doesn't like scrolling the `<body>` (sometimes).

Comment: @Pointy I'm using `window.scroll` so the `window`/`body`/`documentElement` (whichever is applicable for webkit, which I think is `documentElement`)

Comment: maybe u need to the detect the iframe to be loaded and then use scrollTo

Comment: @AlexGarulli That is exactly what I'm doing and is exactly what is not working. That's what I'm trying to workaround.

Comment: maybe this ...would help http://blog.futtta.be/2010/03/03/5-tips-to-tackle-the-problem-with-iframes/

Comment: maybe -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `focus()`?

```
function scrollY(i) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "<a style='position:absolute;left:0;top:" + i + "px' href='#'></a>";
  div = div.firstChild;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  div.focus();
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a known bug [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225456/jquery-scrolltop-does-not-work-in-scrolling-div-on-mobile-browsers-alternativ) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38505&thanks=38505&ts=1350315570) .

The following did a trick for me:

- Switch off overflow style by adding {overflow:hidden}
- Call scrollTo
- Switch on style by setting {overflow:scroll}

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the bug. I hadn't found that anywhere. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work on the `window`, the `documentElement`, nor the `body`. :( If what you were trying on was the window, could you share your code? Thanks

Comment: I used it on div. What if you try to use div inside the iFrame and scroll it using the trick that I mentioned.

Comment: As I said in my question, I want to leave the page as unmodified as possible. Wrapping the page in a `<div>` to scroll it, especially only for this one browser, is not really a viable option for me unfortunately. This is testing code for the page, so scrolling should really be the only major modification as long as it can be helped.