# scrollTop() not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll

This code works as expected on desktop but it doesn't work on mobile browsers

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 690) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
                $('.contact').fadeIn(500);
            }
            if ($(window).scrollTop() < 800) { 
                $('.contact').fadeOut(500);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225456/jquery-scrolltop-does-not-work-in-scrolling-div-on-mobile-browsers-alternativ)