# Scroll in webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i am developing a homepage needed in a webview for an app for both iOS and Android.

I am having some problems with finding a javascript scroll function that works in webview.

I have tried *window.scroll()*, *window.scrollTo()* and *scrollIntoView()* and all works fine when i test them in chrome on my computer but none of them work in the webview.

Can anyone help me finding out how to scroll in a webview?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: i already tried scrollTo() which the one solution suggested in that post... But thanks.

Comment: Are you using the $(window) selector as mentioned in the solution in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208883/android-3-0-js-scrolltop-not-working-on-chrome-webview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)?

Comment: Is that not only for JQuery? i am using vanilla JS currently

Comment: Ah, yes it is. Poor assumption on my part. Have you tried the native equivalent `window.scrollTo`? I guess what I'm asking is, what element are you targetting?

Comment: Yes this is the exact code i have tried: window.scrollTo(0, 29);
Will add "window" to my post